# Why am I am getting 404 errors when I try to access my newly-installed CruiseControl.NET Dashboard?

Tags: iis-6, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, windows-server-2003

I've just got to the bottom of this, and couldn't find the problem documented anywhere, so thought I would post the question (and answer) for future reference:

I've just installed CruiseControl.NET on a (virtual) Windows Server 2003 and I can't access the Dashboard. CruiseControl (ccnet.exe) runs fine, and IIS6 is up and running, and the the CruiseControl installation installed the Dashboard app under Default Web Sites as "ccnet". It's pointing to the dashboard folder, and the dashboard files are visible in IIIS Manager, but when I try to access http://localhost/ccnet I get a 404: Page Not Found error. I get this whether I use IE or Chrome, or try to Browse the site from IIS Manager.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET was Prohibited, and needed to be Allowed - in IIS Manager, click on Web Service Extensions under the server, select ASP.NET and click Allow.